# How to align multi-line text using css?

Tags: css

I am displaying client details, when I displayed address in mulitlines other information is not displaying from the begining.here is my code.

```
 <div class="contactsheader">
     <div class="contactheaderrow"> Address</div>
     <div class="contactheaderrow"> Phone</div>
     <div class="contactheaderrow"> Email</div>             
 </div>
 <div class="contactsdata">
     <div class="contactdatarowwrap"> {{names.address}}</div>
     <div class="contactdatarow"> {{names.phone}}</div>
     <div class="contactdatarow"> {{names.email}}</div>             
 </div>
```

my css is:

```
.contactsheader{
    width: 80%;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(62,95,135);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    padding-left: 1%;
}

.contactheaderrow{
   width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI'; 
}

.contactsdata{
    width: 80%;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 1%;

}
.contactdatarow{
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:justify;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';    
}
.contactdatarowwrap{
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI'; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

here address is displaying in 2 lines then phone and email are also displaying in second line. how to display them in begining line.

Answer (score 0):

Im having trouble understanding your question, but I *think* you are asking about a vertical alignment property for a row of data where once cell wraps and forces the row to be higher than a single line? if so the solution is `vertical-align: top;`

add this to your CSS:

```
.contactdatarowwrap, .contactdatarow {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Also, since you are essentially creating a table, a look at the `display: table*;` may be worth your time.